# Calculate probability and consecutive events in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, probability

My dataset has 575 rows and 368 columns and it looks like this:

```
   NUTS3_2016 URAU_CODE FUA_CODE  X2018.01.01.x X2018.01.02.x X2018.01.03.x    ...
1      AT130   AT001C1  AT001L3    0.46369280     0.3582241     0.2777274      ...
2      AT211   AT006C1  AT006L2   -0.04453125    -0.3092773    -0.3284180      ...
3      AT312   AT003C1  AT003L3    1.02993164     0.9640137     0.6413086      ...
4      AT323   AT004C1  AT004L3    1.21105239     1.4335363     1.2400620      ... 
...    ...      ....    ...            ...            ...           ....       ...
```

I want to calculate the probability that x>2.5 for each row.

I also want to calculate for how many **consecutive** days x remains >2.5 for each row.

What are your suggestions?

Many thanks

---

Attempt:

```
A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
B <- c(1:5) 
C <- c(1:5)
x <- data.frame(A,B,C) 
x$prob <- rowMeans(x[-(1)]>2)
x
#   A B C prob
# 1 a 1 1    0
# 2 b 2 2    0
# 3 c 3 3    1
# 4 d 4 4    1
# 5 e 5 5    1
```

Comment: `rowMeans(data[-(1:3)]>2.5)`

Comment: Doesn't  `rowMeans` just calculate sums and means for each row?

Comment: The proportion of a logical variable is computed as means

Comment: i think something is missing. Try with this 
``A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
B <- c(1:5)
C <- c(1:5)
x <- data.frame(A,B,C)
x$prob <- rowMeans(x[-(1)]>2)``

In the last three rows `prob` should be equal to 1.

Comment: "Counting" in most programming languages is done by summing a logical. And calculating a proportion is taking the mean of a logical. Note that Onyambu's suggestion is `rowMeans( data[-(1:3)] > 2.5 )`, not `rowMeans(data[-(1:3)])`. Try it and see!

Comment: @nflore I've edited that example in your comment into your question, with the results shown. It looks perfect to me, could you please explain what seems wrong about it to you? Use `rowMeans` for proportions, `rowSums` for counts.

Comment: Ah, I see you've now added *consecutive* to the question. Is that only for the count, or does consecutiveness play into the proportion as well? For the count, in case there are runs that dip above and below 2.5, e.g., `1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1` do you want the maximum number of consecutive days, or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the fundamental thing. In your example, I want the streak of three 3s to be calculated as `3`, because they are three numbers bigger than 2. In another row, e.g. `1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2`, I want the streak (4,3,4,5) to be calculated as `4`, because there are four numbers bigger than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rle` for finding the length of the maximum streak.

```
## Some sample data:
set.seed(47)
data = matrix(rnorm(24, mean = 2.5), nrow = 3)
data = cbind(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), as.data.frame(data))
data
#   ID       V1       V2       V3       V4        V5       V6        V7       V8
# 1  A 4.494696 2.218235 1.514518 1.034250 2.9938202 3.170779 1.7966118 2.749148
# 2  B 3.211143 2.608776 2.515131 1.577544 0.6717708 2.418922 2.4594218 2.159584
# 3  C 2.685405 1.414263 2.247954 2.539602 2.5914729 3.764241 0.9338379 2.917191

data$max_streak = apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) with(rle(x > 2.5), max(lengths[values])))
# ID       V1       V2       V3       V4        V5       V6        V7       V8   max_streak
# 1  A 4.494696 2.218235 1.514518 1.034250 2.9938202 3.170779 1.7966118 2.749148          2
# 2  B 3.211143 2.608776 2.515131 1.577544 0.6717708 2.418922 2.4594218 2.159584          3
# 3  C 2.685405 1.414263 2.247954 2.539602 2.5914729 3.764241 0.9338379 2.917191          3
```

Comment: Thank Gregor. After more than a year, I found myself struggling again with this code. Is that the same when we apply the condition to a column? ex: `data$mean <- apply(data[-1],1,mean)`, then `data$max_streak = apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) with(rle(x > data$mean), max(lengths[values])))`

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. The second argument of `apply` is `MARGIN`. `MARGIN = 1` applies the function to rows, `MARGIN = 2` applies the function to columns. If you want to apply the function to a column you can't use identical code, you need to change the `MARGIN = 1` to `MARGIN = 2`.

Comment: Please, refer to the question I just opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451296/using-rle-function-with-condition-on-a-column-in-r